# Spring requests preprocessing per session

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'd like create **Spring** request Interceptor which will be able to get some data from session and change some **@Autowired** components before request.

I can create Interceptor and register it, but it can't get access to session beans:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class TokenInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyServicePerSession myServicePerSession;


    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(myServicePerSession.getName()); // NullPointerException!!!

        return true;
    }
}
```

Above in the method **preHandle(...)** per each request I get **NullPointerException**.

Here is my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    //...   

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new TokenInterceptor());
    }
}
```

How I said everything work fine except injecting **MyServicePerSession**.

I will really appreciate if you can give me advice about it, or some other ways to solve that problem.

Comment: Your interceptor isn't a spring managed bean and as such will not be injected. Move the `new TokenInterceptor` to a `@Bean` annotated method instead. Also imho your approach is dangerous and flawed, components are singleton by default changing wired dependencies per request is going to lead you to suprising results (imagine what could happen with 10 concurrent requests...).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set a new object but you have to set a spring bean.

```
 new TokenInterceptor() // is not spring bean


@Autowired private TokenInterceptor tokenInterceptor;

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor); 
    // You have to set bean here
}
```

If this doesn't work, you can check this http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s02.html

Comment: Could you say how to do it?

Comment: I don't know how by using that way @Autowire MyServicePerSession, because here just a bean definition inside which I should Autowire my service. Anyway your link is quite interesting to have a look at it.